# How to Connect Externally hosted website with AWS CLoudfront CDN

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am hosting my site on Vultr and I want to connect it to CLoudfront CDN. How to do this? I have tried but it shows error that origin connectivity issue.

Comment: You can use any publicly accessible endpoint as your CloudFront origin. What problem are you having?

Comment: When I am connection is show origin connectivity error

Comment: Are you connecting to the origin over HTTPS? If so, is CloudFront forwarding the Host header so the origin can terminate TLS? Check your Cache/Origin Request Policies. I believe CloudFront returns a 502 Bad Gateway response to the viewer in this case.

Comment: I was hosting my site in vultr and was trying to connect to aws cloudfront. I had already hosted my site in EC2+cloudfront and it was working very fine. But after 6 months I moved my site to vultr but I have no idea of connecting vultr with AWS CLoudfront.